# Filter out an array of objects based on internal key and return a new array with initial objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, momentjs

I have an nested array of objects like this

```
[
    {
        id: "12",
        milestones: [
            { id: "1", dueDate: "2021-06-11T10:41:27.140Z", donation: 89.99 },
            { id: "2", dueDate: "2021-06-13T08:45:49.101Z", donation: 0 },
            { id: "3", dueDate: "2021-11-18T06:25:56.000Z", donation: 0 }
        ],
        title: "Project 1"
    }, {
        id: "13",
        milestones: [
            { id: "4", dueDate: "2021-11-29T10:26:06.000Z", donation: 29 }
        ],
        title: "Project 2"
    }
]
```

Here, 2 Projects with each project containing 3 and 1 milestones respectively. I am looking to filter the projects array based on milestone's duedate key and pass it forward so I can filter the project's table. Now my dropdown component passes a string like 'Q1 2020' or 'Q3 2021'. In the below effort I am trying to filter out the projects array where the due date (on conversion into quarter num) matches the value from dropdown component.

```
const handleQuarterChange = (quarterValue) => {
    filteredProjects = projects.map(project => project.milestones.filter(milestone => {
        const quarterNum = moment(milestone.dueDate).quarter()
        const year = moment(milestone.dueDate).format('YYYY')
        return `Q${quarterNum} ${year}` === quarterValue;
    }))
    return filtredProjects;
  };
```

What's happening is I am getting filtered array of milestones, not the project.

Comment: Please may you use standard JS notation to demonstrate object/array structures? `0:
id:` is much harder to read

Comment: That `.map()` call should be a `.filter()` call. And the `.filter()` a `.some()`.

Comment: @Andreas Sure lemme try

Comment: @evolutionxbox Didn't have idea about it. I think its formatted now.

Comment: @Andreas Doesn't work

Comment: Then start debugging because it should work. And please make this question an actual [mcve] - or at least describe what "doesn't work" means as this phrase is totally useless ;) -> [How d I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to group dueDate under milestones in one array and flatten it. It was done by chaining the higher order functions map, filter and then flatten it.
So, the resulting array becomes

```
['Q1 2020', 'Q2 2021', 'Q3 2022']
```

Thanks to reactiflux community on discord.